# How can i measure time of loading my UI Screens in my web application? Any tools available to do that?

Tags: user-interface, testing, automated-tests

I want to measure the time to load each screens and actions in my web application. Is there any easy way to do this? I am thinking of doing manually using stop watch? Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: IE: `F12` -> `UI Responsiveness` ... any modern browser comes with built-in tool or has plugins ready for this.

Comment: Thanks @Filburt. I don't know why people is giving negative marks for a valid question.

Comment: Downvote tooltip: *"This question does not show any research effort..."* seems reason enough for Downvoters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE: F12 -> UI Responsiveness ... any modern browser comes with built-in tool or has plugins ready for this.  –  Filburt

Use Timeline option in Chrome Developer Tools.